# Handling Application event in Utility Bar component

Tags: lightning, lightning-events, utility-bar

I am using a utility bar in a lightning application. I am having a component on the contact record page, from where I am firing an Application event and having a handler on a component which is in Utility Bar.

The Utility bar is not handling the event. Is there any way to handle an Application event in a component inside the utility bar.

Comment: I have the same issue, they aren't getting handled, I only see lightning:events created like "lightning:tabCreated". The documentation doesn't say anything about event limitations

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce utility bar doesn't / can't handle application events. It can only handle standard lightning events like `lightning:tabCreated`. None of the documentation mentions this limitation.